# Script to turn off laptop keyboard if USB keyboard is present

Tags: shell-script, keyboard, xinput

My laptop keyboard is broke (<kbd>Esc</kbd> keeps randomly being pressed, can't fix it), so I've bought a USB keyboard instead. I want to write a script that will run at login which will check if my USB keyboard is connected, and disable my laptop keyboard if so.

I want to use xinput to do this. for background, the correct command to disable device with ID 14 would be:

```
xinput set-int-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

I have what I thought was a reliable method of making sure that I am disabling the correct device by listing, grepping, cutting to get the ID number, and then using it in the correct command like so:

`xinput --list | egrep "AT Translated" | cut -d "=" -f 2| cut -d "[" -f 1 | xargs -I {} xinput set-int-prop {} "Device Enabled" 8 0`

However even this gives a fault:

```
unable to find device 14
```

I'm not sure why that is (first question), but I was wondering how I'd go about checking to see if the USB keyboard is there? I need an if function obviously, something which checks if **any** result is returned when I grep the string "USB USB Keykoard"  [yes that spelling is wrong but what appears on my list] from `xinput --list`. So my second question is, how do I write that if function?

Comment: What's about `udev` script? I did so with USB-mouse.

Comment: Please tell me a little more, I haven't used udev before. The method I use above is only because I understand it!

Comment: That's quite simple: you need to detect actions of attaching and detaching of USB-keyboard, and run your scripts on them. My example for mouse: `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{INPUT_MOUSE}="1", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0.0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/eddy/.Xauthority", RUN+="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=1"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{ID_INPUT_MOUSE}="1", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0.0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/eddy/.Xauthority", RUN+="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0"`

Comment: its a fair point... but even with Eddy_Em's (good) asnwer, I still can't do it as i'm too much of a novice. I've been googling udev without much success...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem with your shell command is here:

```
| cut -d "[" -f 1
```

This leaves you with an argument of `14` (the number 14 followed by several spaces; note that markdown isn't displaying it for some reason). Since the argument that `xinput` is looking for is `14` instead of `14` (14 plus several spaces), the command fails.

Instead, use the space instead of the `[` as the delimiter in this section:

```
| cut -d " " -f 1
```